# Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext - tried all solutions from google search

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting following error.

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Here is my code.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <!--parent>
        <groupId>com.charter.aesd.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>charter-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </parent-->
    <groupId>com.charter.metaproxyapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>metaproxyapimiddle</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>metaproxyapimiddle</name>
    <description>API to interface between POM middleware and the MetaSwitch components</description>
    <properties>
        <aws.sdk.version>1.11.810</aws.sdk.version>
        <cxf.version>2.5.0</cxf.version>
        <cxf.codegen.plugin.version>2.5.0</cxf.codegen.plugin.version>
        <jaxb2-basicsVersion>0.6.3</jaxb2-basicsVersion>
        <config.client.version>2.4.3</config.client.version>
        <aws.lib.version>1.3.12</aws.lib.version>
        <commons.utils.version>1.44.0</commons.utils.version>
        <cxf.bundle.version>2.7.10</cxf.bundle.version>
        <swagger.version>1.5.10</swagger.version>
        <commons.schema.version>1.69.0</commons.schema.version>
        <callerid-middle-client.version>0.0.16</callerid-middle-client.version>
        <metaproxycache-middle-client.version>2.0.0</metaproxycache-middle-client.version>
        <archaius.deployment.environment>local</archaius.deployment.environment>
        <tomcat.port>8888</tomcat.port>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                    <id>charter-release</id>
                    <name>Charter Advanced Engineering Artifactory</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.global.dev-charter.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            </repository>
            <snapshotRepository>
                    <id>charter-snapshot</id>
                    <name>Charter Advanced Engineering Artifactory</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.global.dev-charter.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>charter-public</id>
                <name>Charter Advanced Engineering Artifactory</name>
                <url>http://nexus.global.dev-charter.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>charter-public</id>
            <name>Charter Communications Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://nexus.global.dev-charter.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Versions 3.2.1 & 4.0 of commons-collections should not be used due to identified security vulnerabilities (see http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/576313) -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.charter.aesd.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>charter-starter-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-analysis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- middle service client lib dependencies -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.charter.aesd.metaproxycache</groupId>
                <artifactId>metaproxycache-middle-client</artifactId>
                <version>${metaproxycache-middle-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.charter</groupId>
            <artifactId>txnlogging-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- config client for password decryptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.charter</groupId>
            <artifactId>config-client</artifactId>
            <version>${config.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.sauronsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>jave</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticache-java-cluster-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.61.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jmock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmock-cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.bundle.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Cassandra Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.carmatechnologies.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.charter.aesd</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-schema</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.schema.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.charter.aesd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-utils</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/wsdl</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>boot</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-run</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <archaius.deployment.environment>${archaius.deployment.environment}</archaius.deployment.environment>
                        <logback-lib.env>local</logback-lib.env>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <path>/metaproxyapimiddle</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven War -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>metaproxyapimiddle</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.codegen.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/NWSAP_WebServices/ShService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/NWSAP_WebServices/ShServiceTyped.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                            <!-- <defaultOptions> <extraargs> <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg> <extraarg>-all</extraarg>
                            </extraargs> </defaultOptions> <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                            <includes> <include>NWSAP_WebServices/*.wsdl</include> </includes> <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg> <extraarg>true</extraarg> </extraargs> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <!-- Attach sources to jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema-generate-1</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <addTestCompileSourceRoot>true</addTestCompileSourceRoot>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.metaswitch</generatePackage>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>EAS_WebServices/*.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
                            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/catalog.cat</catalog>
                            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <strict>false</strict>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema2-generate</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <addTestCompileSourceRoot>true</addTestCompileSourceRoot>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/MV_WebServices</schemaDirectory>
                            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/catalog.cat</catalog>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>com.metaswitch.ems.soap.sh.mvb</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <strict>false</strict>
                            <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
                            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema3-generate</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/catalog.cat</catalog>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/xsd/binding</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <bindingInclude>bindings.xjb</bindingInclude>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>com.charter.metaproxyapi.entity</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</source>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <bannedDependencies>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections:(,3.2.1]</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:(,4.0]</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </bannedDependencies>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration></configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <archaius.deployment.environment>local</archaius.deployment.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local-tunnel</id>
            <properties>
                <archaius.deployment.environment>local-tunnel</archaius.deployment.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I checked similar posts but it didn't help. Mine is web application. I am not able to figure out the reason of this error.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate Configuration from this file. Usually, my starter classes contain only @SpringBootApplication annotation